# Is $\sum\frac1{p^{1+ 1/p}}$ divergent?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is $\displaystyle\sum\frac1{p^{1+ 1/p}}$ divergent? How can we prove that it is divergent or convergent in analytic number theory?
I know what bound of the n-th prime number is, and that its order is $n\log(n)$.
Maybe we can use the divergence of $\displaystyle\sum\frac1{n^{1+ 1/n}}$ to show that. I'm not sure that $\displaystyle\sum\frac1{n^{1+ 1/n}}$ is divergent, but I think it is. 
So would you please help me with this ? Can you help me in finding a proof for it ?
Thank you very much, friends.

Comment: Even if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}$ diverges, that doesn't tell you much, since all we know is that this sum is larger than the sum with primes. If  it converges, however... Also see [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write math on this site. Welcome to math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 21):

This is a great question. But you can show that 
$$\frac 1{p^{1+1/p}} > \frac 1{2p}$$
since $2^p >p$, and thus your series diverges.