# Is there a monotonic $f$ such that $\sum f(n)$ diverges but $\sum f(p)$ converges?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

(where the former summation is over natural numbers $n$ and the latter is over prime numbers $p$, and $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a monotonic function.)

For the class of functions $f_s(n) = \frac 1 {n^s}$, the sum over the primes converges iff the sum over $\mathbb{N}$ does (and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106526/is-sum-frac1p1-1-p-divergent) perturbs this class of functions by asking about the case $f(n) = \frac 1 {n^{1+\frac 1 n}}$, but again both sums diverge). Indeed, the fact that $\sum \frac 1 p$ diverges is often viewed as a strengthened version of the fact that there are infinitely many primes, saying that the primes are "not too far" from being dense in $\mathbb{N}$.

But since the primes are not dense in $\mathbb{N}$, I'd expect that there should be reasonable functions $f$ whose sum over the primes converges while the sum over $\mathbb{N}$ diverges. (The monotonicity condition I've imposed on $f$ is meant to rule out "stupid" examples such as the characteristic function of the composite numbers. But if there are "non-stupid" non-monotonic examples, I'd be interested to hear about that too.)

I haven't thought about this question enough to see whether the prime number theorem will be all that matters or whether more refined information will be relevant.

Comment: This question was asked over on MO here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30818/sum-fp-over-all-primes-convergent-with-sum-fn-over-all-natural-numbers-diver

Comment: Wow. And even with with the same nondegeneracy requirement. I should have noticed this before asking. I especially like [Pietro Majer's answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/30829/2362) over there, which makes it clear just how little we need to know about the primes to answer the question. Density 0 indeed suffices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the $n$'th prime $p_n \approx n \log n$, we should have
$p_n \log p_n \approx n (\log n)^2$, so $\sum_p 1/(p \log p)$ should converge, but $\sum_{n \ge 2} 1/(n \log n)$ diverges.

Answer (score 4):

If you let $f(n)=\frac{1}{p_n}$, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime, the sum on the reciprocals of the primes:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{p_k}}
$$
Diverges, but for $f(p_n)$ the sum over the reciprocal of the super-primes:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{p_{p_k}}}=.958...
$$
Converges, as well as the function being strictly decreasing.

Comment: Wait am i missing something? How is thos obvious?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN For the divergence of the first sum, [Euler's Proof](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes#Euler's_proof) is nice. For the convergence of the second, you need to make some asymptotic arguments similar to the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

A function such as $\frac{1}{n\ln{n}}$ should work. Proving that it works might require some heavy machinery like the prime number theorem.